# AWS Lambda node.js 'ping' module permission error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, ping

I am importing 'ping' npm module in my AWS Lambda and trying to run the function for ping probe.

```
pingRegion = async (region) => {
        let res = await ping.promise.probe(`dynamodb.${region}.amazonaws.com`);
        console.log('ping response time ',res.time);
}
```

The node_modules structure is imported fine and there are no file level permissions or path issue.

But when I test the lambda, I see this promise error. How do I give my lambda permission to execute this? Thanks for any support in advance.

> Unhandled Promise Rejection   {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: ping.probe: there was an error while executing the ping program. . Check the path or permissions...","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ping.probe: there was an error while executing the ping program. . Check the path or permissions...","stack":["Error: ping.probe: there was an error while executing the ping program. . Check the path or permissions...","    at ChildProcess. (/var/task/node_modules/ping/lib/ping-promise.js:61:19)","    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)","    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)","    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)","    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)","    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: ping.probe: there was an error while executing the ping program. . Check the path or permissions...","    at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)","    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

AWS Lambda does not support ICMP.

> Q: What restrictions apply to AWS Lambda function code?

> Lambda attempts to impose as few restrictions as possible on normal language and operating system activities, but there are a few activities that are disabled: Inbound network connections are blocked by AWS Lambda, and for outbound connections, only TCP/IP and UDP/IP sockets are supported, and ptrace (debugging) system calls are blocked. TCP port 25 traffic is also blocked as an anti-spam measure.

- https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263968